# Redux - createStore. Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type 'DeepPartial<any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

When I start compilation I always gets a stack error. Which says that my `initialState` in `store` is broken or someone else. Moreover, my app is compile normally if I just cut off `initialState` prop from `store`, but it's not a good solutions.

I also admit that it's work normally on `.js` file version of the app. Seem like redux have some problems with the TypeScript.

Error:

> TS2345: Argument of type '{ titleSwitch: string; }' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type 'DeepPartial'. Property 'titleSwitch' is
>   incompatible with index signature. Type 'string' is not assignable to
>   type 'DeepPartial'.

My part of code:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducer from './reducers'

const initialState = {
  titleSwitch: false
}

const store = () => {
  return createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState // TS Error
  )
}
```

Tested on:

```
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"typescript": "^3.1.1",
"webpack": "^4.16.5"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the code works in JS but fails only because of typing in TypeScript, I'd suggest you to use "any" to ignore it:

```
const store = () =>
  createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState as any
  )
```

Now you're going to ask me: but why??? What is all the point of TypeScript if you just bypass problems whenever you like.

The reason for that is that if you are doing this for work, you need to consider the value of fighting with the type system all the time:

- Either it helps you avoiding mistaking, making development easier, that's the real motivation for strict typing
- Either it plays against you, preventing you doing something legal in JS, it won't make your code more robust because the code in question is something you never really touch (in other words: if using the right typing doesn't change anything in the outcome)

TypeScript has been invented with [flexibility in mind](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~lopes/teaching/inf212W12/readings/rdl04meijer.pdf) and that makes its true power when interoperating with JS libraries. Using perfect and strict typing everywhere makes sense only with languages that have been designed that way from the beginning and this is not the case for JS.

Now don't get me wrong. I'm pretty sure there is a solution to your problem. My reasoning is more about: do you actually need to solve it? Will it brings something useful to your application? Sometimes it doesn't worth it.

Comment: Oh, thank you! This is really work! So, I cannot say that I actually need my `initialState` as `any` type checking, probably, it'll be an `object`. That means that I set my `initialState as object` and it's also works normally. Anyway I think I need more practice with TypeScript. But, for now thank you again! :)

Comment: Good explanation philosophically!

Answer (score 4):

I think Ceciles answer is a good one. I would just like to add that the DeepPartial type is kind of a recursive Partial which works really well when you use multiple reducers combined with `combineReducers`. Your case is basically too trivial for a typical redux state because the leafs of the state are not objects that can be „Partial“ised.

So yeah, for this playground case TS doesn’t provide much value. Once your state and reducers get more complex, type checking should work pretty well again and you can remove the any-cast.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of type mismatch, probably between a reducer and an initialState.

For me it was because I used too general interface for `action` in reducer:

```
interface FluxStandardAction {
  type: string
  payload?: any
  error?: boolean
  meta?: any
}
```

So reducer return value `action.payload` was of type `any` when it must've been of type `string`

See https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript

Comment: This answer put me on the right track. I specified the return type of my reducer explicitly, and the error changed from what OP had to a return statement in the reducer. I ♥ TypeScript